# system time change impact to postgresql database processes

Tags: postgresql, datetime

What is the expected behavior for postgresql processes when system time is changed?

For eg: A case is seen with postgres autovacuum process that, it is not working after time has been changed and only solution is to restart the  Database.

Comment: Minor clock changes should have no effect. If you make big clock changes you should probably restart services like PostgreSQL.